# Where are all the recruitable named settlers?

Tags: fallout-4

Apparently there are named settlers scattered across the commonwealth that you can recruit.  In doing so, if you assign them to a level 3 vendor, it will be upgraded to a level 4 vendor that can sell even better gear.

For example: [Ann Hargraves](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Anne_Hargraves)

Who and where are the rest of these named settlers?

Also, how does this affect the stock when you have multiple vendors of the same type?

Small spoilers:

> The vault tec rep boosts whatever vendor he's assigned too but not to the level of a level 4 vendor, what happens if I have him and a named settler assigned to the same type of vendor?

Comment: Tina Deluca in Vault 81 - if her brother dies
Sheffield I Diamond city - give him Nuka Cola

Comment: Trader Rylee can be found outside Longneck Luckowski's Canary, I think, I've also found Doc Anderson at the campsite near Westing Estate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Vault-Tec rep boosts the trading emporium - that is what he should be assigned to. Some of them have unique items to sell which is why it is a good idea to collect them plus they also have better standard equipment.

[There is a full list of the T4 vendors and what they should be assigned to here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_merchants#.22Level_4.22_merchants).

Comment: You can link directly to the level 4 section: [like this](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_merchants#.22Level_4.22_merchants)

Comment: Might be better to copy and paste that section into the answer

Comment: Agree with @z. This is a fairly short list, so it would be best to keep the full contents within the actual answer text. Link to source is definitely recommended (and, in some cases, required by the source's license), but the answer should not be reliant upon the link.